# Redirecting to pages depending on conditionals in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, conditional-statements

Given is an application with 3 pages:

- "Mainpage"
- "PrivatPage"
- "UserManagementPage"

After successful login the user is redirected to a *"PrivatPage"*. On the *"PrivatPage"* the user has the possibility to return to the *"MainPage"* or to go to the *"UserManagementPage"*. The part with the redirecting from the "MainPage" to the "PrivatPage" works.
The code looks like this:

```
import PublicPage from "./components/PublicPage";
import PrivatePage from "./components/PrivatePage";
import UserManagementPage from "./components/UserManagementPage";
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state;
};

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const accessToken = this.props.accessToken;

        console.log(accessToken);
        let workspace;
        if (accessToken) {
            workspace = <PrivatePage />;
        } else {
            workspace = <PublicPage />;
        }

        return <div className="App">{workspace}</div>;
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**But how do I use the conditionals to get to the "*UserManagementPage*" ?**

Answer (score 1):

if you consider functional components, you could use `BrowserRouter` as follows with `react-router-dom`.
If you need to handle authentication, you can f.e. build a custom `<PrivateRoute />` component and use this on your protected routes instead of `<Route />`. I always keep these routes in a separate file and import them in `App.js`.
Here for demo purposes routes in `App.js`:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
// import your page components
// and add everything else you want to add to your component

const App = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/private" element={<PrivatePage />} />
          <Route path="/public" element={<PublicPage />} />
          <Route path="/user" element={<UserManagementPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to private blocks answer you would then in your components use the

```
<Redirect to='/your-route' />
```

You would then create a boolean state variable and once it return true you could redirect immediatley like this (where you are rendering jsx):

```
render() {
    {booleanState && <Redirect to='/your-route' />}
}
```